# How does this foreach loop code work in php?

Tags: php

I'm having trouble understanding how the foreach loop works in this code. My understanding is that $Score is assigned the arrays of $Die1 + $Die2, but how does $Score gain the value of 1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1? Shouldn't it be 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6 in a sequence since that's how the values are listed in the $FaceValues array? Is there something that's happening in the foreach statements that I'm missing? Can anyone could elaborate on the double foreach statements here?

```
$FaceValues = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

    $ScoreCount = array();
                    for($PossibleRolls = 2; $PossibleRolls <= 12; ++$PossibleRolls){
                        $ScoreCount[$PossibleRolls] = 0;
                    }

                    foreach ($FaceValues as $Die1) {
                        foreach ($FaceValues as $Die2) {
                            // all possible combinations
                        ++$RollCount;
                            //  increment RollCount

                        $Score = $Die1 + $Die2;
                            // 1,2,3,4,5,6
                            // 6,5,4,3,2,1

                        ++$ScoreCount[$Score];
                    }
                }

                    foreach ($ScoreCount as $ScoreValue => $ScoreTimes){
                        echo "<p> A combined value of $ScoreValue occured $ScoreTimes of $RollCount times. </p>";
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration $Die1 is 1 and $Die2 is 2.  So it begins at 2 and goes up to 7.  Then the inner loop is finished and the outer loop proceeds to set $Die1 to 2.  You should then see the number 3 through 8.

You can use `echo` or `var_dump()` and `exit()` to print the values at each step and stop if you're having trouble following-along.